# Storing x>y info

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to store some relations between variable values for analysis purpose.
For example: `x>y`.

Is there any data structure I could use to store this relation? Or, do I need to compute `x>y` every time?

If there is not something like that, please suggest me a method to store this info. 
 I want to store the condition `x>y` itself not the result, true or false. Values of `x` and `y` change and then I examine them to update whether it is `x>y` or `x<y`.

Comment: `bool` variables are good to do that.

Comment: Will either `x` or `y` change between you need to do `x>y`? Then no there's nothing to store the relation (except a function which returns the result of `x>y`). Else store the result in a `bool` variable.

Comment: `bool state = x > y;`

Comment: Can you show some example code how you would use the stored relations?

Comment: I want to store `x>y` itself not the result ,  true or false. Values of x and y change and I examine them then update whether it is x>y or x<y

Comment: Then the only solution is a function returning the result of `x < y`.

Comment: if you'd better explain in the question what would be the use case, the question would be upvotable. Also the answer seems to be a perfect fit for what you want, but this is only clear from your comment, but not from the question alone. I suggest you to give a short example code

Comment: @R.Omar You can use a `std::function` variable and a lambda expression then.

Comment: how about create a class that stores references to both x & y, and then override the bool operator() to comapare them.  Perform a std::bind() (comparable to the idea of the lambda).  There are so many options, but are any of them clearer than if (x<y)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lambda expression. For example

```
int x = 10;
int y = 5;

auto condition = [&x, &y]() { return x > y; };

std::cout << condition() << std::endl;

y = 15;

std::cout << condition() << std::endl;
```